# Auto-Format TextField input SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app that I want to take in time interval inputs in a TextField. I am hoping to auto-format the input to enforce structure of the string it will be. For example, if a user inputs the numbers in order 2, 3, and 9 it formats as 0:23.9, if a user inputs the numbers 7,3,4, and 6, it would format as 7:34.6, if a user inputs 6, 3, 5, 7, 9 it formats as 63:57.9, etc. Is there a way to get the app to format so a user does not need to type in the colon or period and only inputs the numbers? Also if there is a suggestion for better parsing time interval inputs then interpreting that from a string, it would be highly appreciated.